# How to determine which source code requested an image with Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I need to install locally on my laptop my Magento Web site which is hosted at my ISP. I've grabbed all source and DB and managed to connect everything, except for images. I'm not able to see images from sliders, or from the catalog of products.

From the Firefox developer instruments, I've checked the catalog page and I cannot see any 404 for the images. So there's no component requesting the images.

I then went to the online site and had a look at the image from the Firefox Network panel:

[image]

The image path you can see is not available in the Web Server so I really don't know into which part of the site actually requested the image.

Is it possible to determine from the Network Panel which exact component (e.g. a CSS, a Javascript etc) has requested the image? I don't mind at all if that is available just in Chrome.

Comment: In Chrome you can hover the `Initiator` column in the grid view (shown when you click `x` to the left of Headers on your screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

Both the Chrome and the Firefox DevTools provide a way to show the origin of a request within their *Network* panels.

In Chrome you can see that info in the *Initiator* column:

[image: *Initiator* column for network requests in Chrome DevTools]

In Firefox it is called *Cause*:

[image: *Cause* column for network requests in Firefox DevTools]

The Chrome DevTools currently (as of Chrome 78 vs. Firefox 70) provide more information for where exactly the request came from than the Firefox DevTools. Therefore I have created a [feature request for the Firefox DevTools to add more detailed info for the cause of network requests](https://bugzil.la/1230922) some time ago.